# Flaky onSuccess of Future.sequence

Tags: scala, sequence, future, intermittent

I wrote this method:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{ Success, Failure }

object FuturesSequence extends App {
  val f1 = future {
    1
  }

  val f2 = future {
    2
  }

  val lf = List(f1, f2)

  val seq = Future.sequence(lf)

  seq.onSuccess {
    case l => println(l)
  }
}
```

I was expecting Future.sequence to gather a List[Future] into a Future[List] and then wait for every futures (f1 and f2 in my case) to complete before calling onSuccess on the Future[List] seq in my case.

But after many runs of this code, it prints "List(1, 2)" only once in a while and I can't figure out why it does not work as expected.

Comment: The application is exiting before the callback can be executed.

Comment: Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612517/execution-context-without-daemon-threads-for-futures

Comment: As others have said. The default execution context runs your futures on daemon threads which doesn't stop the JVM from exiting. If this is for a quick test the easiest thing would be to use Await.result on the seq

Comment: So is changing the execution context the only way to do this ? Or is their another approach with the right behavior and the current execution context (maybe a blocking step at the end of the asynchronous phase, when I'm waiting for all the results to be return isn't that bad ?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this for once,

```
import scala.concurrent._
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.util.{ Success, Failure }

object FuturesSequence extends App {
  implicit val exec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool)
  val f1 = future {
    1
  }

  val f2 = future {
    2
  }

  val lf = List(f1, f2)

  val seq = Future.sequence(lf)

  seq.onSuccess {
    case l => println(l)
  }
}
```

This will always print `List(1,2)`. The reason is simple, the `exec` above is an ExecutionContext of threads (not daemon threads) where as in your example the ExecutionContext was the default one implicitly taken from `ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` which contains daemon threads.

Hence being daemon, the process doesn't wait for `seq` future to be completed and terminates. if at all `seq` does get completed then it prints. But that doesn't happen always

Comment: when writing futures like this do the futures ever timeout? Asking because I'd prefer a future over thread in case I want to have a return type

Comment: futures by themselves dont get timed out. Unless you explicitly try canceling it. Even in that case, its just the interrupt status of the thread that may be set, and nother more.

Answer (score 2):

The application is exiting before the future is completes.

[You need to block until the future has completed](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#blocking). This can be achieved in a variety of ways, including changing the ExecutionContext, instantiating a new ThreadPool, Thread.sleep etc, or by using methods on `scala.concurrent.Await`

The simplest way for your code is by using `Await.ready`. This blocks on a `future` for a specified amount of time. In the modified code below, the application waits for 5 seconds before exiting.

Note also, the extra import `scala.concurrent.duration` so we can specify the time to wait.

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.util.{ Success, Failure }

object FuturesSequence extends App {
  val f1 = future {
    1
  }

  val f2 = future {
    2
  }

  val lf = List(f1, f2)

  val seq = Future.sequence(lf)

  seq.onSuccess {
    case l => println(l)
  }

  Await.ready(seq, 5 seconds)
}
```

By using `Await.result` instead, you can skip the `onSuccess` method too, as it will return the resulting list to you.

Example:

```
val seq: List[Int] = Await.result(Future.sequence(lf), 5 seconds)
println(seq)
```