# Scala making parallel network calls using Futures

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, future

i'm new to Scala, i have a method, that reads data from the given list of files and does api calls with
the data, and writes the response to a file.

```
listOfFiles.map { file =>
  val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile(file)
  val data = bufferedSource.mkString
  bufferedSource.close()
  val response = doApiCall(data)  // time consuming task
  if (response.nonEmpty) writeFile(response, outputLocation)
}
```

the above method, is taking too much time, during the network call, so tried to do using parallel
processing to reduce the time.

so i tried wrapping the block of code, which consumes more time, but the program ends quickly
and its not generating any output, as the above code.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

listOfFiles.map { file =>
  val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile(file)
  val data = bufferedSource.mkString
  bufferedSource.close()
  Future {
    val response = doApiCall(data) // time consuming task
    if (response.nonEmpty) writeFile(response, outputLocation)
  }
}
```

it would be helpful, if you have any suggestions. 
(I also tried using "par", it works fine, 
I'm exploring other options other than 'par' and using frameworks like 'akka', 'cats' etc)

Comment: it returns Either[String, String], and i use pattern matching and extract the data

Comment: Your main-thread exits and since the global ExecutionContexts' Threads are daemonic, your process exits when main exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Jatin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28086797/5205022) instead of using default execution context which contains deamon threads

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

define execution context with non-deamon threads

```
implicit val nonDeamonEc = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool)
```

Also you can use `Future.traverse` and `Await` like so

```
val resultF = Future.traverse(listOfFiles) { file =>
  val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile(file)
  val data = bufferedSource.mkString
  bufferedSource.close()
  Future {
    val response = doApiCall(data) // time consuming task
    if (response.nonEmpty) writeFile(response, outputLocation)
  }
}

Await.result(resultF, Duration.Inf)
```

`traverse` converts `List[Future[A]]` to `Future[List[A]]`.