# scala global ExecutionContext vs ExecutionContextExecutorService

Tags: scala, future, executorservice

I'm playing with scala Futures with default global context and my own `ExecutionContext`.

I'm curious how `global context` is shutdown after all executions. Because if I create my own `ExecutionContext` I have to manually shutdown.

Example,

**1) Using global executionContext,**

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

object ParallelTasksWithGlobalExecutionContext {

  private val data: Iterable[Input] = Iterable("data1", "data2", "data3")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val f: Future[Unit] = Future.traverse(data) { d =>

      println(s"[${Thread.currentThread().getName}]-Firing $d")
      processData(d)

    } map { processed =>
      processed.foreach(p => println(s"""[${Thread.currentThread().getName}]-$p"""))
    }

    Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
  }

  type Input = String
  type Output = String

  def processData: (Input => Future[Output]) = data => {
    Future {
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      s"[Thread-${Thread.currentThread().getName}] data $data is processed."
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
$ sbt "runMain ParallelTasksWithGlobalExecutionContext"
[info] Running ParallelTasksWithGlobalExecutionContext 
[run-main-0]-Firing data1
[run-main-0]-Firing data2
[run-main-0]-Firing data3
[scala-execution-context-global-59]-[Thread-scala-execution-context-global-58] data data1 is processed.
[scala-execution-context-global-59]-[Thread-scala-execution-context-global-59] data data2 is processed.
[scala-execution-context-global-59]-[Thread-scala-execution-context-global-60] data data3 is processed.
[success] Total time: 6 s, completed Apr 1, 2018 12:44:36 AM
```

*After the execution is completed, application is terminated.*

**2) Using own ExecutionContext** - the application does not terminate after all executions are done until I manually `.shutdown`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, ExecutionContextExecutorService, Future}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object ParallelTasksWithCustomExecutionContext {

  private val data: Iterable[Input] = Iterable("data1", "data2", "data3")
  implicit val singleThreadContext: ExecutionContextExecutorService = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3))

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    Future.traverse(data) { d =>

      println(s"[${Thread.currentThread().getName}]-Firing $d")
      processData(d)

    } onComplete {
      case Success(processed) =>
        processed.foreach(p => println(s"""[${Thread.currentThread().getName}]-$p"""))
        //singleThreadContext.shutdown()
      case Failure(f) =>
        f.printStackTrace()
        //singleThreadContext.shutdown()
    }

  }

  type Input = String
  type Output = String

  def processData: (Input => Future[Output]) = data => {
    Future {
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      s"[Thread-${Thread.currentThread().getName}] data $data is processed."
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
$ sbt "runMain ParallelTasksWithCustomExecutionContext"
[info] Running ParallelTasksWithCustomExecutionContext 
[run-main-0]-Firing data1
[run-main-0]-Firing data2
[run-main-0]-Firing data3
[pool-7-thread-1]-[Thread-pool-7-thread-1] data data1 is processed.
[pool-7-thread-1]-[Thread-pool-7-thread-2] data data2 is processed.
[pool-7-thread-1]-[Thread-pool-7-thread-3] data data3 is processed.
<hangs>
```

And this is JVisualVM Thread monitor,

[image: jvisual-vm]

**My question is how scala's global context terminates automatically without asking the client?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala `global` context is created with usage of `Thread` factory which makes `Threads` daemons, so they (threads) won’t prevent the JVM from exiting once all user threads have finished their execution.

Check `ExecutionContextImpl` method `def createDefaultExecutorService(reporter: Throwable => Unit): ExecutorService`.

Comment: That explains it. Also found an answer here - [Execution context without daemon threads for futures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16612517/432903)