# Program not terminating when using Futures

Tags: scala, file, concurrency, future

I'm trying to concurrently run a function on each file in a directory. Sadly whenever I use Futures my program doesn't want to terminate (runs forever). I have tried using `Await.result()` with the same result :/

When running the code it executes fine, even "finish?" gets printed and then it hangs...

Heres my code. (I'm new to Scala)

```
val execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)
implicit val execContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(execService)

val futures = for (file <- filesList) yield Future {
   println(file)
   // theFunc(file)
}
val seq = Future.sequence(futures)
seq.onComplete {
   case Success(x) => println("finish?")
   case Failure(e) => println(e)
}
```

Comment: Try `Await.ready(Future.traverse(filesList)(theFunc), Duration.Inf)` where `theFunc` already returns a **Future**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sadly I still can't get it to terminate :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Executors.newFixedThreadPool` uses under the hood [`defaultThreadFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#defaultThreadFactory--) which creates non-daemon thread

> Returns a default thread factory used to create new threads. This
> factory creates all new threads used by an Executor in the same
> ThreadGroup... Each new thread is created as a non-daemon thread

Because these are non-daemon threads the program does not terminate. On the other hand, for example, `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` creates [daemon](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/daa51f59f7f54fbe0db0b9fd3ee99317781bf1d9/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/ExecutionContextImpl.scala#L96) threads

```
val threadFactory = new DefaultThreadFactory(daemonic = true,
                                             maxBlockers = getInt("scala.concurrent.context.maxExtraThreads", "256"),
                                             prefix = "scala-execution-context-global",
                                             uncaught = (thread: Thread, cause: Throwable) => reporter(cause))
```

where we note `daemonic = true`, so the following program would terminate at the end

```
implicit val execContext = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val futures = for (file <- filesList) yield Future {
   println(file)
   // theFunc(file)
}
...
```

Based on

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16612739/5205022
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28086797/5205022